# React : Prop not updated inside of a map function

Tags: reactjs

Edit : [Codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-lederberg-b92bq?file=/src/App.js)

Here is a simplified version on my parent component :

```
export default function Parent() {
  // State
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(1);
  const [source, setSource] = useState('https://packagingeurope.com/downloads/7475/download/danone-05.03.20.jpg');
  const [steps, setSteps] = useState([
    {
      title: 'Prediction Initiated',
      value: 1,
      loading: false,
      completed: false,
      active: false,
    },
    {
      title: 'Prediction in Progress',
      value: 2,
      loading: false,
      completed: false,
      active: false,
    },
    {
      title: 'Prediction Finished',
      value: 3,
      loading: false,
      completed: false,
      active: false,
    },
  ]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (status) {
      const newSteps = steps;
      newSteps[status - 1].active = true;
      if (status > 1) {
        newSteps[status - 2].completed = true;
      }
      if (status === 3) {
        newSteps[status - 1].active = false;
        newSteps[status - 1].completed = true;
      }
      setSteps(newSteps);
    } else {
      // Do nothing
      console.log('No status match');
    }
  },
  [status]);

return (
<div className="container-fluid">
  <Timeline status={status} steps={steps} source={source} />
</div>
);
}
```

And here is my child component :

```
export default class Timeline extends React.Component {

  renderSteps() {
    const { steps } = this.props;

    return steps.map((step, index) => {
      console.log(step);
      console.log(steps);
      return (
        <div key={`test${index}`}>
          {step.title}
          {step.active && <span>is active</span>}
          {step.loading && <span>is loading</span>}
          {step.completed && <span>is completed</span>}
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { status, steps, source } = this.props;

    return (
        <div className="timeline">
          {this.renderSteps()}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

When i console.log `steps` props inside my child component, I see that they are correctly updated. (When status === 1, the first step `active` property is `true`)

But when i console.log `step` (inside my map function), none of the properties are updated. (When status === 1, the first step `active` property is `false`)

You can see on the capture below that something is not right (I already encountered this problem but unfortunately I can't remember how I solved it, and I am wondering if it's because of the `useEffect` hooks which I didn't use before this project.

[image]

Thank you for your help

Edit : [Codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-lederberg-b92bq?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: You can't really trust the dev console, somehow by the time a value is printed to console, it can have been updated already. It is common to see this kind of inconsistencies. If otherwise your program is working fine, don't worry about it.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I wouldn't worry about the console if the code was working fine, but I don't see my <span>s being rendered when they should be.

Comment: Hi @RebootGG, checkout the return of your Timeline class. There is a fragment close </> but you dont have the fragment open <>.  I think it could be this because I copy and paste your code and its showing the span to me.

Comment: Thank you for your input Luis. Unfortunately this is only because I mistyped it from my code. The fragment is definitely in my code. If it's working for you I guess i missed something

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto could you share your code ? I've made a codesandbox (see edit in original post) and i still don't see the spans "is active", "is loading", or "is completed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

Since I got this code from another developer, I didn't understand everything that was implemented. I went to the React documentation to understand where the problem was coming from.

By passing a second parameter to the `useEffect` function, [React can skip the effect](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) and will not re-render the component for performance issues if there is not any change. As my status doesn't change (I change it manually for the moment), my component was not refreshing.

By adding `[steps]` width  `[status]` inthe second parameter, everything works.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (status) {
      const newSteps = steps;
      newSteps[status - 1].active = true;
      if (status > 1) {
        newSteps[status - 2].completed = true;
      }
      if (status === 3) {
        newSteps[status - 1].active = false;
        newSteps[status - 1].completed = true;
      }
      setSteps(newSteps);
    } else {
      // Do nothing
      console.log('No status match');
    }
  }, [status, steps]);
```